# Using the document form object, how do you refer to a form element which is grouped by name into an array?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with some inputs that are grouped into an array by their name:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="sibling[0][name]" />
    <input type="text" name="sibling[0][dob]" />

    <input type="text" name="sibling[1][name]" />
    <input type="text" name="sibling[1][dob]" />
</form>
```

I'm trying to use javascript to access the element by name. How would I refer to it? I've tried things like:

js:

```
var formEl = document.myForm.elements[sibling][0][name]; //not correct
var formEl = document.myForm.elements.sibling[0][name]; //not correct 
var formEl = document.myForm.sibling[0][name]; //not correct
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use bracket notation, so you can supply the identifier as a string (where `[` and `]` have no special meaning).

```
var formEl = document.myForm['sibling[0][name]'];
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/VCbnS/).

Comment: I thought this was using some sort of `eval` at first...(saw the answers before question) :P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is supposed to be HTML, those aren't valid names.  From w3 html4, for example:

```
ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
```

Of course, that doesn't mean it won't work in some browser.

I would suggest you give them IDs by some convention, then use document.getElementById() or document.getElementsByTagName().

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
document.getElementsByName("sibling[1][name]")[0]
```

Comment: document.getElementsByName(name) returns an array of elements which match that name.  Adding the [0] references the first element and if your not using the same name for different elements you know your desired element will be the first element of the returned array.